# Laravel, Проверить на существование поля id

Tags: php, laravel

Как проверить существует ли уже такой `id` в таблице, а если существует, то как обновить всю строку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB::table('users')
                ->where('id', 1)
                ->update(array('column' => 1, 'column2' => 2, 'columnN' => N));
```

Comment: а как проверить существует ли такой id?

Comment: `$name = DB::table('users')->where('id', 1)->pluck('id'); if(isset($name)) { ... }` Также можно через whereExists

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете модели а именно в данном случаи модель пользователя.

```
$user = User::findOrNew($id); #найти пользователя с данным ID или создать новую инстанцию юзера.
        $user->fill(['name' => 'Vasya Pupkin']); #Заполнить обьект данными (если были - перепишутся на новые, если нет - запишутся как новые)
       $user->save(); #Можем использовать метод save(), Laravel сам знает или обьект уже есть или его надо записать в базу как новый.
```

Или же в 1 строку:

`$user = User::findOrNew($id)->fill(['name' => 'Vasya Pupkin'])->save();`